# How to echo a parameter from a class using PHP?

Tags: php

I want $foo->display(); to display Hello World

Here is what I tried:

```
class MyAttribute
{
    public function init($var)
    {
        $this->setString($var);
    }
    public function display()
    {
        $this->setString = $var;
    }
}

$foo = new MyAttribute("Hello World");
$foo->display();
```

Comment: Use constructor

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the [`return`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) keyword to pass the variable back, however that is not your issue, consider the following:

```
class MyAttribute {
  private $attr;

  public function __construct($attr)
  {
    $this->attr = $attr;
  }

  public function get_attr()
  {
    return $this->attr;
  }
}

$attr = new MyAttribute('Hello World');

echo $attr->get_attr();
```

The constructor executes first when the class is instantiated and we set the property `$attr` with the variable that is passed to said constructor.

In the `get_attr` functionm the important part to notice is the `return` keyword which I have linked you to the documentation for it above.

You don't necessarily need a constructor, you can add another function called `set_attr` which sets/changes the value of `$attr` but seeing as you are using the constructor in your original code, I've left it in.

**Live Example**

[Repl](https://repl.it/repls/WildScaryHandwritingrecognition)

**Reading Material**

[PHP OOP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is a way to do it with $foo->display();

Comment: @JohnSmith no doubt, but that is merely function naming. You can change `get_attr` to `display` and it would still work but that wasn't why your code wasn't working originally.

Comment: @Script47 Can you explain to me why did you put private $attr;?

Comment: @JohnSmith so you can't access the property directly (`$obj->attr`) and you have to use the defined "getter". If you read the linked **Reading Material** you'll understand it all a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use __construct because PHP will automatically call the __construct() method/function when you create an object from your class.

we can provide a value for the $par property when we create our MyAttribute objects.

```
class MyAttribute
{
    private $var;
    public function __construct($var)
    {
        $this->var = $var;
    }
    public function display()
    {
        return $this->var;
    }
}

$foo = new MyAttribute("Hello World");
echo $foo->display();
```